# How to add attributes to shapefile with Python and pyshp?

Tags: python, pyshp

I'm using [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) for creating a shapefile. I need to populate tens of fields with values using the `record()` method of `shapefile.Writer`. I have those values as a list, but have no idea how to send it to the method without enumerating them as `w.record(values[0], values[1], etc.)`.

Comment: see  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57635/updating-attributes-using-pyshp/57797

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer after mailing to the author of this library: just use `w.record(*attrs)`.