# Editing shapefile adding fields with values with pyshp

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, pyshp

I'm trying to add some fields to a shapefile using pyshp. The code I have to far is:

```
import shapefile

# Read in our existing shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader(r"C:\...\Edit_SHP\TracksLines.shp")

# Create a new shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(r"C:\...\Edit_SHP\TracksLines_edited.shp")

# Copy over the existing fields
w.fields = list(r.fields)

# Copy over the records
for shaperec in r.iterShapeRecords():
 w.record(*shaperec.record)
 w.shape(shaperec.shape)

w.field('test')
```

The issue is that when I try to add a new field all the records already present on the shape are messed up.

How can I keep the same numbers of records, when adding new fields?

[image: Original attribute table]

[image: Edited shpfile]

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://geospatialpython.com/2013/04/add-field-to-existing-shapefile.html

Comment: Just tried, but it doesn't work, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: look at the answers in  [Updating Attributes using Pyshp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57635/updating-attributes-using-pyshp/57696#57696)